# Create a dynamic UITableView

Tags: iphone, xml, arrays, xcode

Hello to all friends of StackOverflow, I am in front of another problem and I will try to resolve it with you. Let's say I have this XML its fields will be different each time but the tag will remain unchanged.

```
<people>
    <item id="1">
        <title>xxx</title>
        <phone>xxx</phone>
        <street>xxx</street>
        <city>xxx</city>
        <district>xxx</district>
    </item>
    <item id="2">
        <title>xxx</title>
        <phone>xxx</phone>
        <street>xxx</street>
        <city>xxx</city>
        <district>xxx</district>
    </item> 
<people>
```

I read this XML with NSXMLParser. What I want to do is enter the data into an array dynamically, for example: if the xml returns me the page with a single tag "item" array will be populated by a single item element, while in the dictionary there will be other tag (title, phone, street, city, district). In another case, however, if tags "item" are greater in number the array will be populated by more elements "item".

I hope I was clear.

Thanks

Comment: So what's your specific problem? What have you tried? What worked and what didn't?

Comment: my problem is I do not know how to populate the array dynamically taking as a field "item"

Comment: Well, in your XML parser, create a mutable array and whenever you encounter an "item", add another object to the array.

Comment: the problem is that I do not know how to create a field when I find items, I can not understand how can I find the first item, the second etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried NSMutableArray & NSMutableDictionary?

pseudo code like this:

```
NSMutableArray* tempArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for ( node in XML )
{
    if ( found new item )
    {
        NSMutableDictionary* tempDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for ( attribute in item )
        {
            [tempDict setObject:value forKey:key];
        }

        [tempArray addObject:tempDict];
    }
}
```